# How to loop a section of a track?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I have a music file that contains an intro (0:00-0:10) and a looping section (0:10-0:30). There are many libraries and simple solutions to loop a track from end->beginning, but I am having trouble finding a way to loop a track from end->loop start. What is the best way to achieve this?

here is the code I am currently using based off the comments below. It still produces a small gap when looping:

```
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([asset duration]);
CMTime loopStart = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(19.2, 1);
CMTime loopEnd = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds, 1);
NSArray *times = @[[NSValue valueWithCMTime:loopEnd]];

__weak typeof(AVPlayer *)weakPlayer = _player;
self.playerObserver = [_player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:times queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [weakPlayer seekToTime:loopStart];
}];

[_player play];
```

Comment: what audio player are you using? is it possible to get notified of the playback end with the player you are using? if it's, then when your player reaches the end, just put the playhead to the desired audio position programmatically, and play it. it's not hard to achieve. And I recommend you using `AVPlayer` for this task. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, ObjectAL had a demo project that uses two separate audio files to play and intro and then loop a main body of a song without a gap in playback. I've modified it to work with a single audio file:

```
+(ALBuffer *)bufferFromFile:(NSString *)filePath startTime:(float)startTime endTime:(float)endTime
{
    NSURL *url = [OALTools urlForPath:filePath];
    OALAudioFile *file = [[OALAudioFile alloc] initWithUrl:url reduceToMono:NO];

    // Convert the start and end times into frames
    NSInteger startFrame = startTime*file.streamDescription->mSampleRate;
    NSInteger endFrame = (endTime-startTime)*file.streamDescription->mSampleRate;///file.totalFrames-(endTime*file.streamDescription->mSampleRate);

    ALBuffer* buffer = [file bufferNamed:[url description]
                              startFrame:startFrame
                               numFrames:endFrame];
    //as_release(file); // I've commented this out, but I suspect there may be some kind of leak here. Can anyone comment on how to properly release this memory?
    return buffer;
}

-(void)playBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)file withIntroThatLoopsAt:(CGFloat)seconds
{
    // Uses OpenAL for both the intro and the main loop.
    // Uses a callback to start the main loop playing.
    // Note: This only works on iOS 5+.

    _source = [ALSource source];
    _introBuffer= [JAudioEngine bufferFromFile:file startTime:0 endTime:seconds];
    _mainBuffer = [JAudioEngine bufferFromFile:file startTime:seconds endTime:-1];

    [self stop];

    __block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;
    [_source registerNotification:AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED
                             callback:^(__unused ALSource *source, __unused ALuint notificationID, __unused ALvoid *userData)
                             {
                                 [blockSelf.source play:blockSelf.mainBuffer loop:YES];
                                 [blockSelf.source unregisterAllNotifications];
                             }
                             userData:nil];

    [_source play:_introBuffer];
}

-(void)stop
{
    [_source unregisterAllNotifications];
    [_source stop];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch from AVAudioPlayer to AVPlayer, you could use `addBoundaryObserverForTimes:`.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530-CH1-SW19):

> Requests invocation of a block when specified times are traversed
>   during normal playback.

The AV Foundation Programming Guide has an explanation with code sample on how to use this method: [Tracking Time](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW17)

Comment: That was a good idea, but I still have a gap. I'm using m4a, so it should be hardware accelerated. Is there some kind of buffering I have to do? Seeking in the block must be wrong, but I don't know any alternatives. I've editing the original post with some code.

Comment: How are you seeking? seekToTime: has several overloads that allow you to specify precision. E.g. – seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:completionHandler:

Comment: I've tried using each seekToTime method, but have found no difference. The gap is still there.

Comment: Maybe the gap you are noticing is the time spent seeking. Maybe you can use a 2nd AVPlayer that seeks while you are playing back your looping part. In your boundary completion handler you could then switch to that player which has already rewinded to the correct position.